# Unable to make v2 version of API as default route c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, routes

So I have two versions for a controller (and its GET action), lets call it `v1` and `v2`.

`.../Controller/v1/MyController.cs` looks like

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
..
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
        {
        ..
        }
}
```

Notice that this controller has the `[Route("api/[controller]")]` default attribute so that I can access it via `localhost:5000/v1/my` and `localhost:5000/my`.

`.../Controller/v2/MyController.cs` looks like

```
[ApiVersion("2")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
..
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
        {
        ..
        }
}
```

This API is currently accessed by `localhost:5000/v2/my`.

Now, **I want to make the v2 as default API instead of v1**.

So I tried to add `[Route("api/[controller]")]` attribute so my `v2 controller` looks like :

```
[ApiVersion("2")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
..
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
        {
        ..
        }
}
```

Now, when I am trying to run and execute below error on POSTMAN:

```
{
    "Error": {
        "Code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
        "Message": "The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:5000/api/my' does not support the API version '1.0'."
    }
}
```

However, the default route works for the v1 version when it is set. 
I am not sure why is the cause of this. Is it because of the namespace? The location of the controller class contains a v2 in the namespace.

Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In StartUp file, you can set the default Api version

```
services.AddApiVersioning(o => {
            o.ReportApiVersions = true;
            o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            o.**DefaultApiVersion** = new ApiVersion(2, 0);
        });
```